# has_one relationship to the same class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following `Person` class that has a parent that is also another Person. I can't seem to figure out how to get the relations to work.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :mom, :dad

  has_one :mom, :class_name => 'Person', :primary_key => "mom_id", :foreign_key => "id"
  has_one :dad, :class_name => 'Person', :primary_key => "dad_id", :foreign_key => "id"    
end
```

I have added "mom_id" and "dad_id" as integers to my model with a migration. However, when I use the `rails console`, I'm not able to access `mom` or `dad` attributes after settings the `mom_id` and `dad_id`. They still return `nil`.

Any pointers to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you do that won't the Person objects be created infinite number of times. `Person1 has one person who has another person who has a third person and so on ...`

Comment: Well, databases are only so big so it can't be infinite... but theoretically, yes. This is only a simple example of my actual use-case that doesn't have that problem however.

Comment: `has_one` doesn't mean a model must have another model. It actually means it can have at most one object.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a `belongs_to` instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with @Andrew, this should be `belongs_to`

```
belongs_to :mom, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => "mom_id"
belongs_to :dad, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => "dad_id"
```